# my ios developer account can't access “Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles” anymore

Tags: ios

Recently I login my ios developer account and try to access “Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles”, it shows need review the new license agreement. I clicked the Review button, it always jump to this page: http://devimages.apple.com/maintenance/#updateAgreement.

I can't found any agree button on this page. How can I review and agree the program license agreement?

Answer (score 2):

Apple's dev centre was recently the target of a security breach which resulted in the dev centre being made unavailable for 8 days. Apple have since re-enabled the certificates part of the dev centre and you should be able to access it again.

I would suggest removing any cookies and emptying your browser caches, as it seems it's still cached for you.

You can keep up to date on the dev centre's status here: https://developer.apple.com/support/system-status/

Comment: Not all of the dev center is back. My account is scheduled to expire in a few days and that part isn't back yet. This also includes the part that allows you to review the license agreement. So the OP is stuck until that part comes back.

Comment: I didn't say the whole dev centre was back (I only stated that the certificates portion has since been re-enabled). I also gave the status page link which definitely outlines which services are back online. As for your account expiring, Apple have previously stated that if your account is due to expire during this period, it will be extended, and your apps will remain on the store, as seen in this screenshot: http://d.pr/i/bhwg. However, you're correct in that the license agreement section of the site is still offline, I hadn't accounted for that.